# Unable to create Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

Preview access was approved, followed the instructions in the email; I try to create a new Azure SQL Data Warehouse. The delivery failed with an Update SQL database event property `StatusCode:NotFound`.

```
Code 45181 Resource with the name 'xxxxxx' does not exist.
```

What can I do to create the Azure SQL Data Warehouse successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for not responding sooner.  I'm checking with the team to see if there is a more involved answer, but I know that SQL Data Warehouse requires a specific level of SSDT to work properly.  The correct version can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-connect-query/

Can you update to the SSDT version mentioned and let me know if that resolves the issue?